# How to allow field t1.f1 to reference t2.f2 only if t1.f3 is null in microsoft sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, null, constraints, ddl

Just to make things simple: Let's say that we have tables with these definitions:

```
create table t1 (id int primary key, f1 int references t2(f2), f3 int references t1(id) )

create table t2 (id int primary key, f2 int)
```

Would it be possible to make a constraint that only allows f1 to be set when f3 is null? How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's examine the usecases and translate them to a boolean statement:

- If f1 is not set (i.e., it's `null`), there's no problem, and we don't care about f3.
- If f1 is set (i.e.m, it's **not** `null`), f3 must be `null`.

This is a simple `or` condition - `f1 is null or f3 is null`. Once we've understood that, it's a simple matter of adding a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT t1_chk CHECK (f1 IS NULL OR f3 IS NULL)
```